# Google Cloud Speech API did not return all text

Tags: speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am using this API to transcribe a long audio but the result only returned partial text.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-csharp

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe you've reached the quote or length limit? Check out: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas

Comment: I agree with the above. Especially check Asynchronous Requests ~180 Minutes limit which applies to your Asynchronous speech recognition use case.

Comment: The audio is less than 1 min.  I followed this page (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#additional_resources) to set the service account, but when I checked the usage, there was nothing.

Comment: Audio less than 1 min is considered as short audio. You should follow this guide https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize for synchronous recognition. If it never worked, please use the quickstart https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries to make the most basic stuff work, then move to more complex usages gradually.

Comment: I deleted my project and started all over.  I got this error: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.  I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH].  What is wrong?

Comment: I restarted my PC and the credential issue is gone now.  However, the transcribed text still returned partial.  I login to my project and there was no traffic.  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=my-new-project-f-1543253066747

Comment: Seemed like when I paused for a second in my audio file, the service stopped transcribing at that point.

Comment: You can enable automatic punctuation https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation for the API to recognize pause as comma or period to continue the recognition.

Comment: Enabling automatic punctuation still didn't help.

Comment: At this far, I would suggest you open an issue at Public Issue Tracker https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers, provide the sample audio and your code there for Google Support to reproduce and further analyze the issue. You can mention this thread in your ticket to include more context.